# Compiling OpenSSL 1.1.0f with SSLv3

Tags: curl, openssl

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.5 and have compiled from source OpenSSL 1.1.0f and Curl 7.54.1.  When I compile openssl I threw the enable-ssl2 and enable-ssl3 flags:

```
    vbetoglo@helios:~/Downloads/openssl-1.1.0f$ ./Configure enable-ssl2 enable-ssl3 linux-x86_64
Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.0f (0x1010006fL)
    no-asan         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_ASAN
    no-crypto-mdebug [default]  OPENSSL_NO_CRYPTO_MDEBUG
    no-crypto-mdebug-backtrace [default]  OPENSSL_NO_CRYPTO_MDEBUG_BACKTRACE
    no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128
    no-egd          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EGD
    no-fuzz-afl     [default]  OPENSSL_NO_FUZZ_AFL
    no-fuzz-libfuzzer [default]  OPENSSL_NO_FUZZ_LIBFUZZER
    no-heartbeats   [default]  OPENSSL_NO_HEARTBEATS
    no-md2          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip dir)
    no-msan         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MSAN
    no-rc5          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)
    no-sctp         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SCTP
    no-ssl-trace    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL_TRACE
    no-ssl3         [forced]   OPENSSL_NO_SSL3
    no-ssl3-method  [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL3_METHOD
    no-ubsan        [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UBSAN
    no-unit-test    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UNIT_TEST
    no-weak-ssl-ciphers [default]  OPENSSL_NO_WEAK_SSL_CIPHERS
    no-zlib         [default] 
    no-zlib-dynamic [default] 
Configuring for linux-x86_64
CC            =gcc
CFLAG         =-Wall -O3 -pthread -m64 -DL_ENDIAN 
SHARED_CFLAG  =-fPIC -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE
DEFINES       =DSO_DLFCN HAVE_DLFCN_H NDEBUG OPENSSL_THREADS OPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE OPENSSL_PIC OPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 OPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT OPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 OPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m SHA1_ASM SHA256_ASM SHA512_ASM RC4_ASM MD5_ASM AES_ASM VPAES_ASM BSAES_ASM GHASH_ASM ECP_NISTZ256_ASM PADLOCK_ASM POLY1305_ASM
LFLAG         =
PLIB_LFLAG    =
EX_LIBS       =-ldl 
APPS_OBJ      =
CPUID_OBJ     =x86_64cpuid.o
UPLINK_OBJ    =
BN_ASM        =asm/x86_64-gcc.o x86_64-mont.o x86_64-mont5.o x86_64-gf2m.o rsaz_exp.o rsaz-x86_64.o rsaz-avx2.o
EC_ASM        =ecp_nistz256.o ecp_nistz256-x86_64.o
DES_ENC       =des_enc.o fcrypt_b.o
AES_ENC       =aes-x86_64.o vpaes-x86_64.o bsaes-x86_64.o aesni-x86_64.o aesni-sha1-x86_64.o aesni-sha256-x86_64.o aesni-mb-x86_64.o
BF_ENC        =bf_enc.o
CAST_ENC      =c_enc.o
RC4_ENC       =rc4-x86_64.o rc4-md5-x86_64.o
RC5_ENC       =rc5_enc.o
MD5_OBJ_ASM   =md5-x86_64.o
SHA1_OBJ_ASM  =sha1-x86_64.o sha256-x86_64.o sha512-x86_64.o sha1-mb-x86_64.o sha256-mb-x86_64.o
RMD160_OBJ_ASM=
CMLL_ENC      =cmll-x86_64.o cmll_misc.o
MODES_OBJ     =ghash-x86_64.o aesni-gcm-x86_64.o
PADLOCK_OBJ   =e_padlock-x86_64.o
CHACHA_ENC    =chacha-x86_64.o
POLY1305_OBJ  =poly1305-x86_64.o
BLAKE2_OBJ    =
PROCESSOR     =
RANLIB        =ranlib
ARFLAGS       =
PERL          =/usr/bin/perl

SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG mode

Configured for linux-x86_64.
```

I've compile and recompiled curl after having done this as well, but no matter what I do, it always comes back with:

```
vbetoglo@helios:~/Downloads$ curl --version
curl 7.54.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.54.1 OpenSSL/1.1.0f zlib/1.2.8 nghttp2/1.12.0-DEV
Release-Date: 2017-06-14
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy 
vbetoglo@helios:~/Downloads$ curl -3 https://www.google.com/
curl: (4) OpenSSL was built without SSLv3 support
```

Can anyone hint at what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: which curl binary are you using? Can you check "which curl" output. You may be using curl provided with ubuntu, not the compiled one. And please make sure to issue a "ldd <path-to-compiled-curl-binary>" command to ensure that compiled curl is using new openssl library.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add also the flag "enable-ssl3-method"

Your command becomes:

./Configure enable-ssl2 enable-ssl3 enable-ssl3-method linux-x86_64